# Unpacking ZIP packages

Tags: mac, zip

For some ZIP file I end up with an "invalid argument"

[image]

Any ideas?

The file can at the same time be unpacked on another PC.

Comment: What if you try to open from the terminal as:  "unzip file.zip". I saw your other issue on this page too. I would suggest you update your macOS to 10.15.2 first :)

Comment: Please do not upload needlessly large images when you can just capture the error message itself. You can also copy the text portion of the error message and paste it instead of uploading any image, as it's the message that needs to be conveyed, not a screenshot like you originally uploaded!

Comment: Updated as proposed. The issue persists. For the terminal solution: what is the complete command if the zip is located in the downloads folder?

Comment: You can either change directory to `Downloads`, e.g `cd Downloads` and use `unzip 3724Z_Roth.zip` or use `unzip ./Downloads/3724Z_Roth.zip` assuming the PWD is `$HOME`, or from any directory `unzip $HOME/Downloads/3724Z_Roth.zip` or `unzip ~/Downloads/3724Z_Roth.zip`

Comment: You might also want to try downloading the file again as it may be corrupt, unless you actually copied this one file to another computer and it unzipped okay.

Comment: Thanks. using terminal works. What is the reason for that? Any ideas?